# TypeScript React Axios GET Request Returning Empty String Instead Of JSON

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, axios

I'm running into a strange issue when using Axios GET request on my TypeScript create-react-app project.

Currently, I'm running an TypeScript Express app on the back end, and I have a simple route that returns an object:

```
router.get('/api/current_user', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send(req.user);
});
```

When I visit this route via URL, I can see the object perfectly fine. It is a JSON object like this:

```
{
"_id": "randomstring",
"googleId": "randomstring",
"username": "Alexander Le",
"__v": 0
}
```

Perfectly normally so far. Great. **But uh oh..**

**When I make an Axios GET request to this route, I am always receiving an empty string as data.** Here's my axios request:

```
export const fetchUser = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/current_user');
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_USER,
        payload: response
    });
};
```

I checked my network tab and although I always get a status 200, I am always receiving an empty string as data.

**To add onto this, when I change my route response from this:**

```
router.get('/api/current_user', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send(req.user);
});
```

**to this:**

```
router.get('/api/current_user', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send('HELLO');
});
```

**I get the'HELLO' as data. So what's preventing me from receiving the JSON object as data?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you see the response data in the network tab and not only the status 200? Maybe the `Content-Type` header is not set correctly. Can you add a screenshot of the request in the network tab?